# Error in Typecasting SPList to SPDocumentLibrary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am studying custom document template.I have created a ListInstance of type Document Library and also created Module using Visual Studio 2010.Then  I had created a Application page.In its page load i have pasted the following code

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://pc81:2000/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["YbbestCustomDocLib"];
                string urlStr = @"Lists/YbbestCustomDocLib/Forms/Sample.txt";
                lib.DocumentTemplateUrl = urlStr;
                lib.Update();

            }
        }
```

But when i load this application page, at the point of type casting SPList to SPDocumentLibrary i am getting an error "**Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary**".Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["YbbestCustomDocLib"];
SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary) list;
```

or

```
SPList list = web.Lists["YbbestCustomDocLib"];
SPDocumentLibrary lib = list as SPDocumentLibrary;
```

Comment: Working fine now